# Correct output but also Debug Error massage: " Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around

Tags: c

After debugging I recieve a correct output but simultaneously I get Debug Error massage: " Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'arr' was corrupted. Why is it occurred ? How can I correctly rewrite it? I have to solve this problem :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
# define N 21

int main()
{
int arr[N];
int *p, *end, *q;
int i, x;

//initialize the array
for (i = 1; i <= N; i++)
    arr[i - 1] = i;

printf("%d", arr[0]);
end = &arr[N - 1];
p = &arr[1];
while (p < end)
{
    printf(", %d", *p);
    q = p;
    x = *p;
    while (q <= end)
    {
        q += x;
        *q = 0;
    }
    do
        p++;
    while ((*p == 0) && (p < end));
}
printf("\n");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: and your debugging effort?

Comment: The compilation process succeeded and I got the expected answer on the black run screen .But, one second after I recieve this Run-Time warning and Visual Studio stop working..

Comment: fix like [this](http://ideone.com/PljEIz)

Comment: I have already solved it by myself :) thank you very much!